# Calling DefaultHttpClient as a Singleton

Tags: android, constructor, singleton, httpclient

I would like to convert the DefaultHttpClient to a singleton class

```
public class HttpClient {   
private static final String TAG = "&&----HTTPClient-----**";
public static void SendHttpPost (String URL, JSONObject jsonObjSend){

    try{    

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);
}
```

How would I go about this ? Actually I tried some methods of implementing them but it didn't work out for me.

Below is an example of how my singleton should look

```
public class DefaultHttpClient {
static DefaultHttpClient instanceCE;    
public static DefaultHttpClient getInstance(){
    if(instanceCE == null){
        instanceCE = new DefaultHttpClient ();
    }

    return instanceCE;

}

DefaultHttpClient object = new DefaultHttpClient .getInstance(); //calling it here
```

I know this implementation is wrong awaiting your inputs to help me. Thanks !

I've put the final implementation which isn't working.

```
public class HttpClient {
public static DefaultHttpClient instanCE;
private static final String TAG = "&&----HTTPClient-----**";
public static DefaultHttpClient getInstance(){
    if(instanCE == null){
        instanCE = new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
    return instanCE;
}
public static void SendHttpPost (String URL, JSONObject jsonObjSend){

    try{    
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = DefaultHttpClient.getInstance();
            HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code except that your calling it wrongly.

```
 DefaultHttpClient object = DefaultHttpClient.getInstance();
```

Also your names seem to have got mixed up. Rename DefaultHttpClient to something else like MyHttpclient on the first and third line of the singleton.
This should fix it definitely.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

3 things:

**1)** You need to create a private constructor, so that you are sure `getInstance()` is the only way to create an instance.

```
private DefaultHttpClient() {
    // Optional Code
}
```

**2)** `getInstance()` is static so it should be called like this:

```
DefaultHttpClient object = DefaultHttpClient.getInstance();
```

**3)** You are missing closing `}`

**EDIT:**
"I get an error that states that the method is undefined for DefaultHttpClient"

If this is the case make sure you are importing the correct class and not 
`org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be OK, you are just calling it wrong. The getInstance() method is static. So the correct way how to call it is:

```
DefaultHttpClient object = DefaultHttpClient.getInstance();
```

Comment: I saw that mistake and re-tried it but I get an error that states that the method is undefined for DefaultHttpClient. Should I pass instanceCE at SendHttpPost ?

Comment: Rename the singleton class to something else, for example MyHttpSingleton. I think the class names are colliding here. So the final call will be like DefaultHttpClient object = MyHttpSingleton.getInstance();